# Are these languages Regular or Non-regular?

Tags: automata

I have these two languages

$L={\{a^n b^m,n≥m+5,m>0}\}$ Where $∑=(a,b)$

$L={\{a^n b^m,n≥m+5,m≤5}\}$ Where $∑=(a,b)$

As you can see that there is only one difference, the condition of `m` is different.

What my question is that, are these languages regular or non-regular?

If these both languages are non-regular then how can we able to prove that using pumping lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Split $a^n$ into $\color{blue}{a^n}$ and $\color{green}{a^5}$, that is, consider language $$L = \{\color{blue}{a^n}\color{green}{a^5}b^m \mid \color{blue}{n}\geq m, m > 0\},$$ where the two new letters $\color{blue}{a}$ and $\color{green}{a}$ are just two distinguishable letters $a$, and $\color{blue}{n} = n-5$.
- For the second language observe that \begin{align}\{a^nb^m\mid n\geq m+5, m\leq 5\} &= \bigcup_{i=0}^{5}\ \{a^nb^m\mid n\geq m+5, m=i\} \\
  &=\bigcup_{i=0}^{5}\ \{a^nb^i\mid n\geq i+5\}\\
  &=\{a^{\color{blue}{n}}a^5b^0\mid \color{blue}{n}\geq 0\} \cup \ldots \cup \{a^{\color{blue}{n}}a^{10}b^5\mid \color{blue}{n}\geq 0\}.\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: you are saying that both the languages are non-regular?

Comment: In first language, how to choose Pumping length?

Comment: What will  be `w`in first language? I think it will be a^p a^5  b^p

Comment: @Aniq Suppose that there is an automaton with $k$ states that recognizes $L$, consider the word $a^{k+1}a^5b^{k+1}$. Because the automaton has $k < k+1$ states, then when parsing $b$'s some state has to [happen at least twice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). That means that there is a loop and you can use it any number of turns you want, so for any number $x$ there is $y > x$ such that your automaton accepts $a^{k+1}a^5b^{y}$. Surely you can find $y$ so that that word shouldn't be in $L$.

Comment: @Aniq Going back to the pumping lemma, your subword $w$ should be $b^p$, with $uwv = a^pa^5b^p$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#General_version_of_pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)).